# Передача и получение нескольких значений в AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

Я пытаюсь передать и получить несколько значений (строки полученные с URL) через AsyncTask. Подскажите, как это можно сделать? Строки с URL получаю с использованием HttpURLConnection.

В Классе GetBusinessURL (HttpURLConnection) происходит "сборка URL" (generateURL), затем в "getResponseFromUrl" принимается сформированный URL, по нему будет происходить запрос, и получать ответ. В классе APITask, в методе doInBackground получаю на вход url (generateURL с GetBusinessURL), в Business присваиваю то что должно прийти по URL. И дальше нужно передать переменную Business во fragment для парсинга(BusinessFragment), но у меня не получается. Подобных URL будет несколько и они должны передаваться по разным фрагментам

APITask.java (класс AsyncTask)

```
public class APITask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void,String> {
    private String Business = null;
    private String Economy = null;

    public APITask(String business, String economy) {
        Business = business;
        Economy = economy;
    }

    public APITask() {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        try {

            Business = GetBusinessURL.getResponseFromUrl(urls[0]);
            Economy = GetEconomyURL.getResponseFromUrl(urls[1]);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

BusinessFragment.java (во fragment я пытаюсь получить строку с APITask)

```
 public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        APITask apiTask = new APITask();
        apiTask.execute(GetBusinessURL.generateURL());
    }
```

GetBusinessURL.java (HttpURLConnection)

```
public class GetBusinessURL {
    private static final String GET_RSS_POLITICS = "https://www.pravda.ru/politics/export-articles.xml";

    public static URL generateURL(){
        Uri builtUri=Uri.parse(GET_RSS_POLITICS);

        URL url=null;
        try {
            url=new URL(builtUri.toString());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return url;
    }

    public static String getResponseFromUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            Scanner scanner=new Scanner(in);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
            boolean hasInput=scanner.hasNext();
            if (hasInput){
                return  scanner.next();
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Уточните проблему: зачем здесь приведён этот код и что он делает не так, как было задумано?

Comment: @Вася Воронцов , я хочу получить xml строку с URL (что бы в дельнейшем сделать парсинг). В Классе GetBusinessURL происходит "сборка URL" (generateURL), затем в "getResponseFromUrl" принимается сформированный URL, по нему будет происходить запрос, и получать ответ. В классе APITask, в методе doInBackground получаю на вход url (generateURL с GetBusinessURL), в Business присваиваю то что должно прийти по URL. И дальше нужно передать переменную Business во fragment для парсинга(BusinessFragment), но у меня не получается. Подобных URL будет несколько и они должны передаваться по разным фрагментам

Comment: чтобы дополнить текст вопроса, нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: `apiTask.execute(GetBusinessURL.generateURL());` - передан 1 параметр, но ожидается, что их будет не менее 2 (см. `APITask.doInBackground`). Кроме того, *"но у меня не получается"* - что именно? Передать полученные данные или получить эти данные?

Comment: @Вася Воронцов , как мне кажется передать полученные во fragment

Comment: Тогда [этот ответ на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26060197) может помочь